# Extract substring from grep/awk results?

Tags: awk, grep

I have a grep command that finds rows in a file, passes those to awk and prints out the 1st and 15th columns.

```
grep String1 /path/to/file.txt | grep string2 | awk -F ' ' '{print $1, $15}'
```

So far, so good.  This results in a list like this:

```
2023-01-20 [text1]>
2023-01-22 [text2]>
2023-01-23 [text3]>
2023-01-25 [text4]>
```

Ideally, I'd like to add some regex to the awk command so that I get this:

```
2023-01-20 text1
2023-01-22 text2
2023-01-23 text3
2023-01-25 text4
```

My searches have only returned how to use regex with awk to identify fields but not to extract a substring from the results.  Is this possible with awk or some other command?

Comment: If you're using awk you don't need grep. awk has `sub`/`gsub` functions for simple regex replacements. For example: `gsub(/[][>]/,"",$15)` (or perhaps a less "magic" regex: `/[\[\]>]/`

Comment: please update the question with the `grep/awk` commands you're using to generate this set of input; in addition to not needing `grep` if using `awk` ... if using `awk` there's rarely a need for a 2nd `awk` script; net result: there's a good chance your current `grep/awk` code, along with the new requirement, can be replaced with a single `awk` script ... but it's kinda hard to make recommendations without seeing the current `grep/awk` code

Comment: will the 2nd field/column *always* include the `[` and `]>` wrappers?

Comment: Updated with grep/awk command.  I'm more familiar with grep than awk, hence why I started with it.

Comment: @markp-fuso  Yes, it always contains those characters.

Comment: `grep String1` is misleading as `String1` is a regexp, not a string, and that can lead to mistakes. Please fix your example to be either `grep Regexp1 /path/to/file.txt | grep regexp2` or `grep -F String1 /path/to/file.txt | grep -F string2` or whatever else you meant (add `-w` maybe?). Also, don't really just use the words `string` and `text` (or `regexp`) in examples - show truly representative values that can be useful in testing a potential solution. The right solution to your problem depends on everything we don't yet know about it, like what `string` means and what values `textN` has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just basically want to delete the characters `[`, `]` and `>`, you can simply use `tr -d` for this, something like:

```
... | tr -d "[]>"

Linux prompt>echo "2023-01-20 [text1]>" | tr -d "[]>"
2023-01-20 text1
```

Answer (score 3):

One `awk` idea that combines the current code with the new requirement:

```
awk -v s1="String1" -v s2="string2" '                               # feed both search strings in as awk variables "s1" and "s2"
$0~s1 && $0~s2 { print $1,substr($15,2,index($15,"]")-2) }          # if s1 and s2 are both present in the current line then print 1st field and 15th field (sans the "[" "]" wrappers)
' /path/to/file.txt
```

A non-sensical demo file:

```
$ cat file.txt
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a string2 c d e f g h i j k l m n [old]> p q r s t u v String1 x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a String1 c d e f g h i j k l m n [older]> p q r s t u v string2 x y z
```

Running the `awk` script against this file generates:

```
a old
a older
```

Comment: Doesn't affect functionality, but may be more descriptive to use `re1`/`re2` instead of `s1`/`s2` to accent that matching is by regex and not simple string comparison (`index($0,s1)`,etc). And something like `sub(/^\[/,"",$15); sub(/\]>$/,"",$15)` feels less fragile than `substr(..., 2, ...-2)`

Comment: I'm sure that's an elegant solution.  Unfortunately, my awk skills are too basic to properly read/understand it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option removing the leading `[` and trailing `]>` with gsub and an alternation:

```
awk '/String1/ && /string2/ {
  gsub(/^\[|\]>$/, "", $15)
  {print $1, $15}
}' file.txt
```

In `gnu-awk` you could use [gensub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html):

```
awk '/String1/ && /string2/ {
  {print $1, gensub(/^\[|\]>$/, "", "g", $15)}
}' file
```

---

Or find the occurrence of the string using index:

```
awk 'index($0, "String1") && index($0, "string2"){
  gsub(/^\[|\]>$/, "", $15)
  {print $1, $15}
}' file
```